# Using a Serial.Read input to set an lcd cursor on Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

I realize that you can use variables in a lcd.setCursor, but it doesn't work for me when I try to use an integer read off of the serial port. It is possible?

Here is what the relevant parts of my code looks like, at the moment nothing prints:

```cpp
int align

if( Serial.available() ) {
  align = Serial.read();
} 
if( Serial.available() ) {
  lcd.setCursor(align,0);
  lcd.print('test');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the data sent over serial is correct?

Comment: I tried do an lcd.print(align), and it would print out the value.

Comment: It looks like you read the serial, so Serial.available() becomes 0. The second block doesn't run. Take out  "} if( Serial.available() ) {".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you read the serial, so Serial.available() becomes 0. The second block doesn't run. Take out

```
} 
if( Serial.available() ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You sure that's what you want to do? If you are trying to read a number and then move the cursor I think you need to read until the user presses enter('\r') then convert your byte from read() into a integer.

```
char align[100];
while(Serial.available() && i< 99) {
  align[i++] = Serial.read();
}
align[i++]='\0';
lcd.setCursor(atoi(align),0);
```

If this isn't what you want maybe add some sudo code comments so people can follow your train of thought.